# ngrok config to render errors in HTML

Tags: ngrok

I use ngrok to inspect web service errors. The issue that I have is when an error exception is thrown the content of it (in HTML, CSS, JavaScript or JSON) will show up in a particular box in ngrok inspect UI. So, I have to select it, copy-and-paste it to sublime text and save it as HTML to see its content properly, or I should read the code itself. I want to know is there any configuration in ngrok to show me the rendered HTML? Selecting the code and run it in a new page or in an iframe or in the place that its written?

Comment: Asking for us to find off-site resources (e.g. Chrome extensions) is off-topic for Stack Overflow and will likely get your question down-voted and closed. I have edited your question to remove that request.